# Fragment Navigation Animation not working

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, fragment, android-animation

I have a back button in a fragment when I press that back button I want to navigate to the previous fragment. I could have implemented `onBackpressed()` in my fragment but could not find any proper way. My animation is working fine but when I added `popUpTo` and `popUpToInclusive` the animation `animExit` does not work properly. I want to implement animation same as `onBackPressed` between usersFragment(source Fragment) and mainFragment(target Fragment). When I press the mobile back button animation works fine but when I press my application back button `animEnter` works fine but `animExit` does not.

You can see in this [Animation Gif](https://gfycat.com/insidiouswelcomeafricanelephant) of my app that `animEnter` works fine but `animExit` does not.

Is this due to `popUpTo` and `popUpToInclusive`?

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/usersFragment"
        android:name="com.shoaib.firebasechatapp.fragment.UsersFragment"
        android:label="fragment_users"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_users" >


        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_usersFragment_to_mainFragment"
            app:destination="@id/mainFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/usersFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"


            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"

            />
    </fragment>
```